# Reactive Dependent EditText

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I have 3 edit texts dependent on each other. Let me explain:
When user input value into edittext1, it calculates the value for edittext2 and edittext3.
The same occurs for edittext2 and edittext3.
that is, the user with one type of data can calculate 2 other type of data.
But, it is not perfect, I mean, with Data 1, you can calculate Data 2 with result X, but, in 2, if you input X, you will get a similar but not the same result.

well,
I was doing this for each edit text:

```
new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (isSettingText) {
                    return;
                }
                editText1.getText.toString();
                calculateData2BasedOn1();
                calculateData3BasedOn1();
            }
```

And I do the same for 2 and 3 respectively.
Well, I think it is a lot of code and kinda redundant.
I am studying RxAndroid and trying to do it simplified but I can't think of a way to do that. Anybody got any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way is to check which is the views that has the focus, in order to avoid the cyclic propagation of events:

```
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(mEditText1)
    .filter(textViewTextChangeEvent -> mEditText1.hasFocus())
    .subscribe(textViewTextChangeEvent -> {
        updateEditText(mEditText2, calculateText2(textViewTextChangeEvent.text().toString()));
        updateEditText(mEditText3, calculateText3(textViewTextChangeEvent.text().toString()));
    });

RxTextView.textChangeEvents(mEditText2)
    .filter(textViewTextChangeEvent -> mEditText2.hasFocus())
    .subscribe(textViewTextChangeEvent -> {
        updateEditText(mEditText1, calculateText1(textViewTextChangeEvent.text().toString()));
        updateEditText(mEditText3, calculateText3(textViewTextChangeEvent.text().toString()));
});


RxTextView.textChangeEvents(mEditText3)
    .filter(textViewTextChangeEvent -> mEditText3.hasFocus())
    .subscribe(textViewTextChangeEvent -> {
        updateEditText(mEditText1, calculateText1(textViewTextChangeEvent.text().toString()));
        updateEditText(mEditText2, calculateText2(textViewTextChangeEvent.text().toString()));
});
```

There are many way for removing the duplicated code, but I am not sure it will worth it.

Comment: Nice. Why do you think that it the ways to remove the duplicated code doesnt worth it?

Comment: Well, flexibility comes with a cost. If you want things to be more flexible, you need to create more classes, interfaces, more work. There are situations in which you really don't want spend time overcomplicating the architecture just for flexibility that you don't need.
So, if you want to create a component so that you can reuse this part, or you want to add more `EditText`, then probably makes sense, otherwise I think it is good enough.